# Showing the existence of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Please show me the existence of the limit clearly

$$\lim_{\large(h,k)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\vert hk\vert ^{\alpha} log(h^2+k^2)}{\sqrt {h^2+k^2}} =0$$

for $\alpha > \frac12$

Comment: Write $h = r\cos\varphi$ and $k = r\sin\varphi$.

Comment: ...and so $|hk|^{\alpha}=\rho^{2\alpha}|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|^{\alpha}$: among others you want $|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|^{\alpha}$ to be bounded and to use $\rho^{...}\log(\rho)\rightarrow 0$ when...

Comment: But I need to show that the limit approach to zero @DanielFischer

Comment: I am confused. Please on the below answer part, clearly and step by step can you write? I need. Thank you:) @Avitus

Answer (score 3):

We have $|h|,|k|\leq \sqrt{h^2+k^2}=||(h,k)||$ so

$$\frac{\vert hk\vert ^{\alpha} |log(h^2+k^2)|}{\sqrt {h^2+k^2}}\leq \frac{||(h,k)|| ^{2\alpha} |log(||(h,k)||^2)|}{||(h,k)||}=||(h,k)|| ^{2\alpha-1} |log(||(h,k)||^2)| $$

and let $||(h,k)||=t$ so if $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ then $t\to0$ and we have
$$\lim_{t\to0}t^\beta\log(t^2)=0\quad \forall \beta>0$$
so now can you conclude?

Comment: Yes yes got it very well:) thank you so much for helping:)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that when $(h,k)$ is sufficiently close to $(0,0)$ then the function approaches to $0$. What Daniel's comment suggests you to do is to consider such a point $(h,k)$ as having polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$ so that being "close to (0,0)" now means that r is "close enough to 0 and positive". Your function becomes
$$f(r,\varphi) = \frac{r^{2\alpha} \lvert \sin\varphi\cos\varphi\rvert^\alpha \times 2\log(r)}{r}$$

You now need to take this function for $r$ close to $0$, so that 
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{r^{2\alpha} \lvert \sin\varphi\cos\varphi\rvert^\alpha \times 2\log(r)}{r} = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} r^{2\alpha-1} \lvert \sin\varphi\cos\varphi\rvert^\alpha2\log(r)$$

For $\alpha > 1/2$, $2\alpha -1 > 0$ and it is known that $x^\beta\log(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow 0$ and $\beta > 0$. The value $\lvert \sin\varphi\cos\varphi\rvert^\alpha$ being bounded for any value of $\varphi$, this limit is equal to $0$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel Fisher suggested you to use polar coordinates, introducing

$$h=r\cos\varphi,$$
$$k=r\sin\varphi.$$

Using polar coordinates, your limit is

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{\rho^{2\alpha}|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|^{\alpha}\log(\rho^2)}{\rho}, (*)$$

as $(h,k)\rightarrow 0$ is equivalent to $r\rightarrow 0$ and, by definition

$$\sqrt{h^2+k^2}=\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\varphi+r^2\sin^2\varphi}=r\sqrt{\cos^2\varphi+\sin^2\varphi}=r,    $$

as $r>0$. The limit $(*)$ is then

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} 2\rho^{2\alpha-1}\log(\rho)|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|^{\alpha}:=
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} f(\rho)g(\theta)$$

using $\log(\rho^2)=2\log(\rho)$ and introducing the functions

$$f(\rho)=2\rho^{2\alpha-1}\log(\rho),$$
$$g(\theta)=)|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|^{\alpha}.$$

To prove continuity at $(0,0)$ we need to impose

$$2\alpha-1>0 $$

so $f(\rho)\rightarrow 0$ when $\rho\rightarrow 0$ and

$$\alpha\geq 0 $$

to have that $g(\theta)$ is bounded. These two conditions guarantee that the product
 $f(\rho)g(\theta)$ satisfies

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} f(\rho)g(\theta)=0.$$

In other words, we arrive at

$$\alpha>\frac{1}{2} $$
$$\alpha\geq 0 $$

or  $\alpha>\frac{1}{2} $, as claimed.

Comment: Thank you I understand this solution way as well:)

Comment: You are welcome!